# Can't open the initial console on ARM S3C2440 running utuLinux

Tags: linux, console, arm, boot

I try to mount an NFS filesystem to the target board ARM s3C2440. I've started the NFS service and the portmap service. The server operating system is Ubuntu 10.04. I use minicom to communicate with the target board. In the terminal on the server, I typed the command: `showmount -e`

```
Export list for android-desktop:
/utuLinux2.6.24/s3c2440_recover *
```

So the configuration of NFS service is right. The directory `/utuLinux2.6.24/s3c2440_recover` on Ubuntu is the directory which I want to mount to the target board s3c2440. The operating system is on the board is utuLinux.
I powered on the ARM board, and at the utu-bootloader prompt, I set the `bootargs` environment variable before booting:

`$setenv bootargs 'console=ttySAC0 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.2.107:/utuLinux2.6.24/s3c2440_recover ip=192.168.2.213:192.168.2.1:192.168.2.1:255.255.255.0:www.yctek.com:eth0:off`
`$boot`

But I got an error when booting:

```
utu-bootloader=>>>setenv bootargs 'console=ttySAC0 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.2.107:/utuLinux2.6.24/s3c2440_recover ip=192.168.2.213:192.168.2.1:192.168.'
utu-bootloader=>>>boot

NAND read: device 0 offset 0x60000, size 0x200000

Reading data from 0x25fe00 -- 100% complete.
 2097152 bytes read: OK
## Booting image at 32000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-2.6.24.4
   Created:      2008-12-07  16:50:12 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1959328 Bytes =  1.9 MB
   Load Address: 30008000
   Entry Point:  30008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux..........................................................................................................................................
Linux version 2.6.24.4 (lili@lili-desktop) (gcc version 3.4.1) #121 Mon Dec 8 00:50:06 CST 2008
CPU: ARM920T [41129200] revision 0 (ARMv4T), cr=c0007177
Machine: UTU2440
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
CPU S3C2440A (id 0x32440001)
S3C244X: core 405.000 MHz, memory 101.250 MHz, peripheral 50.625 MHz
S3C24XX Clocks, (c) 2004 Simtec Electronics
CLOCK: Slow mode (1.500 MHz), fast, MPLL on, UPLL on
CPU0: D VIVT write-back cache
CPU0: I cache: 16384 bytes, associativity 64, 32 byte lines, 8 sets
CPU0: D cache: 16384 bytes, associativity 64, 32 byte lines, 8 sets
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: console=ttySAC0 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.2.107:/utuLinux2.6.24/s3c2440_recover ip=192.168.2.213:192.168.2.1:192.168.2.1:255.255.25f
irq: clearing pending ext status 00000300
irq: clearing subpending status 00000003
irq: clearing subpending status 00000002
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: 8, 1024 bytes)
timer tcon=00500000, tcnt a4ca, tcfg 00000200,00000000, usec 00001e57
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
console [ttySAC0] enabled
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Memory: 64MB = 64MB total
Memory: 60160KB available (3556K code, 727K data, 472K init)
SLUB: Genslabs=11, HWalign=32, Order=0-1, MinObjects=4, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
net_namespace: 64 bytes
NET: Registered protocol family 16
S3C2440: Initialising architecture
S3C2440: IRQ Support
S3C2440: Clock Support, DVS off
S3C24XX DMA Driver, (c) 2003-2004,2006 Simtec Electronics
DMA channel 0 at c4800000, irq 33
DMA channel 1 at c4800040, irq 34
DMA channel 2 at c4800080, irq 35
DMA channel 3 at c48000c0, irq 36
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
TCP reno registered
NetWinder Floating Point Emulator V0.97 (double precision)
NTFS driver 2.1.29 [Flags: R/W].
fuse init (API version 7.9)
yaffs Dec  8 2008 00:45:24 Installing. 
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
fb0: s3c2410fb frame buffer device
GPIO L3 bus interface for S3C2440, installed
utu2440 LED Driver v1.00
s3c2440-uart.0: s3c2410_serial0 at MMIO 0x50000000 (irq = 70) is a S3C2440
s3c2440-uart.1: s3c2410_serial1 at MMIO 0x50004000 (irq = 73) is a S3C2440
s3c2440-uart.2: s3c2410_serial2 at MMIO 0x50008000 (irq = 76) is a S3C2440
loop: module loaded
nbd: registered device at major 43
dm9000 Ethernet Driver
eth0: dm9000 at c4802300,c4804304 IRQ 53 MAC: 00:12:34:56:80:49
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
em28xx v4l2 driver version 0.0.1 loaded
usbcore: registered new interface driver em28xx
usbcore: registered new interface driver gspca
drivers/media/video/gspca/gspca_core.c: gspca driver 00.60.00 registered
et61x251: V4L2 driver for ET61X[12]51 PC Camera Controllers v1:1.09
usbcore: registered new interface driver et61x251
zc0301: V4L2 driver for ZC0301[P] Image Processor and Control Chip v1:1.10
usbcore: registered new interface driver zc0301
videodev: "vivi" has no release callback. Please fix your driver for proper sysfs support, see http://lwn.net/Articles/36850/
Video Technology Magazine Virtual Video Capture Board (Load status: 0)
Driver 'sd' needs updating - please use bus_type methods
S3C24XX NAND Driver, (c) 2004 Simtec Electronics
s3c2440-nand s3c2440-nand: Tacls=1, 9ns Twrph0=4 39ns, Twrph1=1 9ns
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0xec, Chip ID: 0x76 (Samsung NAND 64MiB 3,3V 8-bit)
Scanning device for bad blocks
Bad eraseblock 972 at 0x00f30000
Bad eraseblock 3615 at 0x0387c000
Creating 3 MTD partitions on "NAND 64MiB 3,3V 8-bit":
0x00000000-0x00060000 : "bootloader"
0x00060000-0x00260000 : "kernel"
0x00260000-0x03ffc000 : "root"
s3c2410-ohci s3c2410-ohci: S3C24XX OHCI
s3c2410-ohci s3c2410-ohci: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
s3c2410-ohci s3c2410-ohci: irq 42, io mem 0x49000000
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using s3c2410-ohci and address 2
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Initial utulinux 2440 Buttons driver!
Todo: mknod c /dev/utu2440-buttons 252 0
s3c2440 TouchScreen successfully loaded
input: s3c2440 TouchScreen as /devices/virtual/input/input0
S3C24XX RTC, (c) 2004,2006 Simtec Electronics
s3c2410-rtc s3c2410-rtc: rtc disabled, re-enabling
s3c2410-rtc s3c2410-rtc: rtc core: registered s3c as rtc0
i2c /dev entries driver
s3c2440-i2c s3c2440-i2c: slave address 0x10
s3c2440-i2c s3c2440-i2c: bus frequency set to 98 KHz
s3c2440-i2c s3c2440-i2c: i2c-0: S3C I2C adapter
S3C2410 Watchdog Timer, (c) 2004 Simtec Electronics
s3c2410-wdt s3c2410-wdt: watchdog inactive, reset disabled, irq enabled
mapped channel 2 to 0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbkbd
drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c: :USB HID Boot Protocol keyboard driver
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbmouse
drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c: v1.6:USB HID Boot Protocol mouse driver
We do iis iomap from here. 
mapped channel 10 to 2
mapped channel 9 to 1
Now we have successfully init dma resourse. 
UDA1341 audio driver for utu2440 has been initialized
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
NET: Registered protocol family 17
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
s3c2410-rtc s3c2410-rtc: hctosys: invalid date/time
eth0: link up, 10Mbps, half-duplex, lpa 0x0021
IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.2.213, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.2.1,
     host=www, domain=, nis-domain=yctek.com,
     bootserver=192.168.2.1, rootserver=192.168.2.107, rootpath=
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.2.107
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.2.107
VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem).
Freeing init memory: 472K
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
         _                     _   _                        
 _   _  | |_   _   _          | | (_)  _ __    _   _  __  __
| | | | | __| | | | |  _____  | | | | | '_ \  | | | | \ \/ /
| |_| | | |_  | |_| | |_____| | | | | | | | | | |_| |  >  < 
 \__,_|  \__|  \__,_|         |_| |_| |_| |_|  \__,_| /_/\_\    http://www.utu.com.cn/utuLinux
```

If it had booted successfully, I could have typed the command `mount /dev/mtdblock2 /mnt` and then in the directory `/mnt` I could have seen the root directry of the ARM board. But now I can't control the console. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can see that the NFS root is getting mounted, the problem is that the system can't access the console after booting. This might be an issue with how `init` is configured. What init system does utuLinux use, and how is it configured? (If there's an `/etc/inittab` file, post it.) Do you have an SSH daemon running on the board? If so you should be able to run commands on it that way.

Comment: THX！I have solvoe this problem.I can't access the console because the file about the console isn't written into the hard-disk.I use the command:
`$tar -xjvf utu-Linux2.6.24_for_utu2440_2008-10-08.tar.bz2 -C /utuLinux2.6.24/`
and found the file `"/dev/console"` couldn't make a node on the disk.so i use:
`$sudo tar -xjvf  utu-Linux2.6.24_for_utu2440_2008-10-08.tar.bz2 -C /utuLinux2.6.24/`
and the file is written to the disk.Now i can access the console!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Could you post this as an answer, to help future visitors who have a similar problem? (You might need to wait a little, the system restricts self-answers for new users but the restriction goes away after a few hours.)

Comment: I'll take your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't access the console because the file about the console wasn't written to the hard disk. I used the command

```
tar -xjvf utu-Linux2.6.24_for_utu2440_2008-10-08.tar.bz2 -C /utuLinux2.6.24/
```

and found that the file `/dev/console` couldn't be created. So I used

```
sudo tar -xjvf utu-Linux2.6.24_for_utu2440_2008-10-08.tar.bz2 -C /utuLinux2.6.24/
```

and the file was written to the disk. Now I can access the console.